# TransactionManagementError when saving model with OneToOne relationship in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to make it so that when a User model is created, it also creates the corresponding MyAppProfile class to go with it.  But when I do so, as I've seen online, I get an error.

> An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.

I've tried various methods to do this, and they give that error when I try it.  I can't figure out why I'm getting that error, or where exactly it's coming from.

My profile class:

```
class MyAppProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="myapp_profile")

    # Other fields for this app's profile go here

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: MyApp Profile for {self.user.username}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


@receiver(post_save, sender=AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        MyAppProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.myapp_profile.save()
```

Edit:

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = UUIDField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            saved = False
            attempts = 0
            while not saved:
                try:
                    if attempts > 5:
                        raise RuntimeError('Max attempts reached trying to save to database.')
                    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
                except IntegrityError:
                    attempts += 1
                    self.id = gen_uuid(length=8)
```

Comment: Where is this error being raised? Can you add the traceback to your question

Comment: The problem is in another part of your code. How you call `user.save()`?

Comment: @iurisilvio added my user model.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show enough code here, but your code probably is running inside a transaction. Something like:

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    profile.save()
```

When the transaction fails with an `IntegrityError`, you can't execute anything else inside this transaction, it is already terminated.